# Foreign Keys or Delete Trigger?

Tags: oracle, database-design, triggers

The tables:

```
SIGN_OBJECT:
ID VARCHAR2(32) PRIMARY KEY, 
DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2(100),
X NUMBER(10,3), 
Y NUMBER(10,3),
...
GEOMETRYID VARCHAR2(32) 

LAMPPOST_OBJECT:
ID VARCHAR2(32) PRIMARY KEY, 
DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2(100),
X NUMBER(10,3), 
Y NUMBER(10,3),
...
GEOMETRYID VARCHAR2(32) 

OBJGEOMETRY:
GEOMETRYID VARCHAR2(32) PRIMARY KEY, 
GEOMETRY MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY, 
...
```

There are many X_OBJECT tables.  Unfortunately the schema designers (in their infinite wisdom) didn't see any crossover between the various object types. I am unable to change these tables without creating much more work.

For each object table there is a trigger that creates the relevant SDO_GEOMETRY value BEFORE insert or update ( GEOMETRYID is unique - it comes from a sequence ). At the moment the trigger calls a package function which inserts the OBJGEOMETRY record and returns the geometryid.

The problem is that if the parent record is deleted I would like the OBJGEOMETRY child record to be also deleted.

Initially I thought this could be done with Foreign Keys cascade delete, but of course the FK requires a Primary Key in the parent table - obviously this won't work.

However, I discovered that actually a FK requires a unique constraint in the parent table. I can make X_OBJECT.GEOMETRYID unique but then I'm finding issues because that GEOMETRYID isn't yet populated in the parent table but the FK requires it exists. I cannot do that inside the trigger ( by setting :NEW.GEOMETRYID ) so do I have to write the GEOMETRYID first and then commit? I'm not sure and this has bad code smell.

So am I wrong? Is this a more suitable case for a delete trigger? or is there something I'm missing.

Thanks.

Comment: Foreign keys require a unique constraint in the referenced table. They don't require a *primary key* constraint, although that's the most common unique constraint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The triggers should fire before insert or update, not after. Then you can set :NEW.GEOMETRYID with the value returned by your package.

Besides, the foreign keys point the wrong way. It should be
    ALTER TABLE x_OBJECT ADD FOREIGN KEY (geometryid) REFERENCES objgeometry(geometryid);

Therefore, you'll need a delete trigger...

Comment: It's not a foreign key - its a delete trigger - as you said its the other way round.

Answer (score 1):

If you insert both the OBJGEOMETRY and the X_OBJECT rows in the same transaction, then you can set the FK to `DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED`.

In that case it will be evaluated at `COMMIT` time, not when you run the `INSERT` statement.